# jquery each add class with delay inbetween

Tags: jquery, loops, delay, each, setinterval

I need to loop through each div .row to add or remove a flip class that has a CSS3 3D transform effect.

When I apply this add/remove class to each ".row" with jquery each(), all the divs get the class ".flip" added or removed at the exact same time. I need this to be delayed so it looks like a domino effect.

Any idea how I can get this working? Or how to add / remove the flip class one by one??

This is what I've found but it is not working:

```
  $('.row').each(function(i){
    if($(this).hasClass('flip')){
      $(this).delay(i*500).removeClass('flip');
    }else{
      $(this).delay(i*500).addClass('flip');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The jQuery `delay()` method only delays the next pieces in the queue of strung together methods using `$(obj).delay(500).addClass('flip');`  It doesn't delay all subsequent lines of code.  (check out the [first example](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and how the code runs its animations side-by-side)

Try using `setTimeout()` instead.

```
$('.row').each(function(i){
  var row = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    row.toggleClass('flip');
  }, 500*i);
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xPgJp/1/)

Comment: You shouldn't need the second parameter to `toggleClass` in this case http://jsfiddle.net/xPgJp/2/

Comment: @Kevin B, that's true.  I think I've just gotten in a habit of using the 2nd param for other conditionals.  Edited to reflect

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you. I tried adding a timeout but use the toggle. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `setTimeout` to do a `delay` effect.

Here is jsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/xQkmB/1/**

```
var i = 0;
var rows = $(".row");
show();

function show() {
    if (i < rows.length) {
        $(rows[i]).show();
        i++;
        setTimeout(show, 1000);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `addClass` function isn't an animation function, so it doesn't get queued, and so runs immediately without waiting for the `.delay()` to finish.

I use this extension to queue non-animated jQuery calls:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.queued = function() {
        var self = this;
        var func = arguments[0];
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this.queue(function() {
            $.fn[func].apply(self, args).dequeue();
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

which in your code would be called thus:

```
$('.row').each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(i*500).queued('toggleClass', 'flip');
}
```

NB: using `toggleClass` instead of a conditional add/remove.