# jQuery delay being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code running but for some reason, no matter where I place the delay the line executes immediately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#team_a_grid, #team_b_grid').on("click", "td.clickable", function(){
    var dot_or_cross ='<span>Dot</span>'
    $(this).delay(3000).removeClass().html(dot_or_cross);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery each add class with delay inbetween](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680803/jquery-each-add-class-with-delay-inbetween)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .setTimeout()

```
$('#team_a_grid, #team_b_grid').on("click", "td.clickable", function () {
    var dot_or_cross = '<span>Dot</span>'
    var $this=$(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.removeClass().html(dot_or_cross);
    }, 3000);
});
```

As pointed out in the comments

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

[**Doc reference**](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: Yep, because `.delay` is only used for animations.

Comment: You mean `var $this = $(this);` ;-)

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://api.jquery.com/delay/ : "The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases."